# Getting errors while installing modules on Odoo8 server (OpenERP)

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, ubuntu-14.04, openerp-8

Always I'm getting errors while installing modules on the Odoo 8 server, following is the error message. OpenERP Server Error:

> `Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 476, in
>   _handle_exception return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 495, in dispatch result
>   = self._call_function(**self.params) File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 311, in _call_function
>   return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
>   return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 308, in checked_call
>   return self.endpoint(*a, **kw) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 685, in __call__ return
>   self.method(*args, **kw) File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py",
>   line 360, in response_wrap response = f(*args, **kw) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 987, in
>   call_button action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {}) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 975, in
>   _call_kw return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 204, in wrapper return
>   old_api(self, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line
>   450, in button_immediate_install return
>   self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install,
>   context=context) File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line
>   204, in wrapper return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line
>   497, in _button_immediate_function registry =
>   openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname,
>   update_module=True) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 322, in new
>   openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status,
>   update_module) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 357, in
>   load_modules loaded_modules, update_module) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 263, in
>   load_marked_modules loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph,
>   progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules,
>   perform_checks=perform_checks) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 162, in
>   load_module_graph registry.setup_models(cr) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 165, in
>   setup_models model._setup_fields(cr, SUPERUSER_ID) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 204, in wrapper return
>   old_api(self, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 297, in old_api result =
>   method(recs, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 2961, in _setup_fields
>   field.setup(self.env) File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/fields.py",
>   line 360, in setup self._setup(env) File
>   "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/fields.py", line 378, in _setup field =
>   dep_model._fields[field_name] KeyError: 'section_id'`

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

OS spec: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: can you please paste whole traceback. Its difficult to trace.

Comment: Hello @Ronak I just updated with full traceback and the OS spec., Thank You.

Comment: Please delete your database and try it again.

Comment: @Ronak I just tried it, by deleting database and created new database, but still getting the same error ... :(

Comment: Please update your odoo8, it is fixed in it. I checked it.

Comment: @Ronak, I hv the latest beta version, "Version 8.0rc1", seems to be no any other nersions available.

Comment: Version 8.0rc1 is updated about 8 days ago. You can find it here https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/fa38c0f6a61982e31d271e0877b784c25448e31a

Comment: @Ronak, Thank You... :) , I 'll try and let u know..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58950/discussion-between-user3440631-and-ronak).